# mypy not recognizing inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance, type-hinting, mypy

Does mypy not recognize inheritance in type hints? It's giving me an error that I'm supposedly using the wrong type when instantiating a class. But the type I'm using is a child class of the type that this class accepts.

I'll illustrate with a simple example:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence
from typing import List, overload, Union


class Parent:
    def my_method(self) -> int:
        return 42


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, some_int: int):
        self.some_int = some_int

    def my_method(self) -> int:
        return self.some_int


class ParentList(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, parent_list: List[Parent]):
        self.parent_list = parent_list

    # ... other code to be compatible with sequence

class ChildList(ParentList):
    def __init__(self, child_list: List[Child]):
        super().__init__(child_list)
```

On the last line mypy gives the following error:

> Argument 1 to "__init__" of "ParentList" has incompatible type "List[Child]"; expected "List[Parent]"mypy(error)

But since each `Child` is also a `Parent` I wouldn't expect this to be incompatible. Am I missing something or is mypy?

Comment: Let's say `ParentList` adds a `Parent` instance to `parent_list` in the constructor. The types allow that! But suddenly your `ChildList` contains `Parent` instances inside a `List[Child]`. That is not allowed! That's why you can't pass the child list to the parent constructor.

Comment: In other words, `List[Child]` is not subtype of `List[Parent]` because `List`(and other mutable containers) is invariant. As a workaround, you can use immutable `Sequence`

Comment: Would it work with a Tuple instead of a List then? Since a Tuple is immutable?